# Choosing Between GDC and DMD

Tags: debugging, version, d, dmd, gdc

I'm new to programming in D.
What are the pros and cons of choosing either DMD (2.061) or GDC (4.6, 4.7 or 4.8, snapshot).
And what GDC version should I pick?
I've successfully built a recent snapshot of GCC-4.8 and GDC-4.8 and it compiles a hello world program.

Here are my thoughts on pros so far:

- **GDC**: More platforms, run-time performance
- **DMD**: compilation-performance, more tested?

What about debugging support through GDB - does it differ between GDC and DMD?

Comment: DMD is the reference implementation but in heavy flux as bugs are found...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use **DMD** as it is the reference implementation and is most widely used. It is also the *most up to date* as new features and fixes are primarily released in **DMD** (but **GDC** and **LDC** are released not too long after **DMD**).

As a newcomer you should consider **DMD** first, until you find specifics, which you need but don't find in **DMD**, then you can consider using **GDC** or **LDC**. Or use them right away, as all compilers share a common frontend from **DMD**, so switching them should not be so problematic (except bugs which may not be the same in all of them).

All 3 compilers currently support 32-bit and 64-bit (alpha/beta?) on Windows and Posix platforms.

Some experimental initiative is taken to support ARM platforms by [**GDC**](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?GdcHacking#WhyGDC) and [**LDC**](http://wiki.dlang.org/LDC#Project_status).

**GDC** and **LDC** may have longer compile times compared to **DMD** which is *lighting fast* - making edit/compile/run cycle a *a pleasure*, while **GDC** and **LDC** generally compile *faster code* which makes them more suitable for *release builds* (of course app testing should be done on the release compiler)